# Removing Users From App Event/Custom Audience from FB IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

For FB IOS SDK: My app events are firing correctly, but I have a use case issue I cannot solve. I'm creating custom audiences from app events, however I cannot figure out how to remove a user from a custom audience (created by app event triggers).

For example, my app has different levels 1-5. I want to send a marketing message to users who are currently on level 3. The problem is if I use my custom audience for level 3 (a user is added to this list when they hit the app event for level 3), it would also include users who are on level 4 and 5. Why? Because they fired the app event for level 3 on their way to level 4 and 5.

How can I remove users from a app event or custom audience using the FB IOS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Exclude audiences in your targeting
Keep everything pretty similar, but add an exclusion when you run your ad. So for your Level 3 campaign, your targeting would be "Include People Who Reached Level 3" and "Exclude People Who Reached Level 4".

**Option 2**: Move from rule-based audiences to explicitly-listed audiences
You can use the [Custom Audience API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audiences-targeting/v2.9) to explicitly add and remove people from your audiences. Pros: It's cleaner. Cons: It requires development work - you'd need to invoke this API either from your server or your app whenever anyone changed levels. Also you'd need to migrate from the current audiences to new audiences. You can mix and match audiences within a campaign, but a single audience is either rule-based or member-based.

Comment: This is amazing. The customer audience API is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!